# SearchControl OnButtonClicked Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this search control which linked to a button

```
<td width="25%">
    <uc1:SearchControl ID="scGreeting"
                       runat="server"
                       TabIndex="3"
                       ReturnType="CodeOnly"
                       AutoPostBack="false"
                       DomainType="Greeting"
                       CodeField="PlatNumber"
                       TextField="IsBooking"
                       OnButtonClicked="scgreeting_ButtonClicked"
                       Condition="CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedOn, 111) AND Status = 0 ORDER BY IsBooking DESC,CreatedOn ASC" />
</td>
```

and I have the `onButtonCliked` event on it but it didn't trigger the button

here is my code calling the event

```
protected void scgreeting_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Collection<Greeting> collGreeting = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectByFieldName<Greeting>("PlatNumber", scGreeting.Value);
    MessageBox.Show("TEST");
}
```

Comment: you added `AutoPostBack="false"`. Change it to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RojalinSahoo is correct you have set `AutoPostBack="false"` means you can't postback in layman language you can't send a request to server because there isn't any `__EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT` to handle the post.

.Net framework automatically adds a `__doPostBack (eventtarget, eventargument)` event in JavaScript and `__EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT` in an hidden field when `AutoPostBack="true"`but when `AutoPostBack="false"`above JavaScript and events are not added thus you won't able to postback even if you have mentioned the event method.

Change **Autopostback** from **false** to **true**.

```
<uc1:SearchControl ID="scGreeting"
                       runat="server"
                       TabIndex="3"
                       ReturnType="CodeOnly"
                       AutoPostBack="true"
                       DomainType="Greeting"
                       CodeField="PlatNumber"
                       TextField="IsBooking"
                       OnButtonClicked="scgreeting_ButtonClicked"
                       Condition="CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedOn, 111) AND Status = 0 ORDER BY IsBooking DESC,CreatedOn ASC" />
```